# Relationship between Galois Correspondence and the Fourth Isomorphism Theorem (Correspondence Theorem)?

Tags: galois-theory, group-isomorphism

Fourth Isomorphism Theorem: Let $L$ be a group and $K$ a normal subgroup of $L$. Then, there is a bijection between the set of groups $H$ with $K\leq H \leq L$ and the subgroups of $L/K$.

Galois Correspondence: Let $L/K$ be a field extension with Galois Group $\text{Aut}(L/K)$. Then, there is a bijection between the set of fields $H$ such that $K\subset H\subset L$ and the subgroups of $\text{Aut}(L/K)$.

I recognise also that the Fourth Isomorphism Theorem can also be stated for rings, and if this is more related, then please use at will. These theorems can be stated very similarly as seen above. Is this the reason for the $L/K$ notation of field extensions (as I have been very confused why the same notation has been chosen)? Does Galois Correspondence imply the Fourth Isomorphism Theorem? If not, what are the links between the two theorems?

Comment: Short answer: no. Both are examples of a "one-to-one correspondence" but there is no further analogy. The correspondence theorem for subgroups of a quotient group does not follow from the Galois correspondence.

Comment: As for the $L/K$ notation, I think it's just because when you read it like a fraction "L over K" it describes the picture of fields, $L$ is over $K$ because it's the bigger field. Or it's collapsing how you'd draw them pictorially into something that fits in a line.

Comment: I feel like subset already does that